# Selenium Webdriver wait on element click?

Tags: c#, selenium, timeout, webdriver

I have been searching for a solution for this, but to no avail. I have a button I'm clicking, that is sometimes taking a long while to return data, and the driver is timing out and just killing the app I guess.

I am trying to use the WebDriverWait class to accomplish this, but the Click() method is not available in the way I'm using it.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));

bool clicked = wait.Until<bool>((elem) =>
{
     elem.Click(); //Doesn't Work
     return true;
});
```

The ImplicitlyWait() method is only for waiting for elements to load, but this times out on Click(), so it can't even look for an element.

The SetScriptTimeout() method just works with executing javascript, which I'm not doing.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to prestomanifesto's solution I can offer a less than ideal solution to that I implemented to solve this issue. It turns out it is throwing an exception - No Response etc... - so I just surrounded it in a try catch then waited for the popup to close, which seems to work fine.

You can substitute whatever you want in your loop, just make sure to put a counter in so it won't loop forever.

```
try
{
    element.Click();
}
catch
{
    cnt++;
    do
    {
      //wait for whatever
      cnt++;
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      // Wait for 30 seconds for popup to close
    } while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(browser.CurrentWindowHandle) && cnt < 30);
}
```

Comment: i am struggling to find a better solution, i have posted here if you can have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967008/webdriverwait-or-implicitlywait-or-explictlywait-nothing-works

Answer (score 14):

try this :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver , 1000) ;
wait.until(ExcepctedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ById("element"));
```

Element can be ID of any element present on the next page you are redirected to  . 
Once Page loads fully then it will start executing your code .

Comment: the problem is that when element.click() is processed, it pauses and waits for around 30 seconds for the .click() method to return. If it doesn't, throws an exception.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Click` you could try to use `SendKeys`. Unlike `Click`, `SendKeys` does not wait for the page to finish loading before resuming code execution. So you can do something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));

elem.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);    
wait.Until<bool>((_driver) =>
{         
     //Check here if results have loaded yet
     return true;
});
```

As a side note, I'm pretty sure `Until` takes in a `IWebBrowser` as an input, not an element, which is why you can't click on `elem`.

Comment: This is a good solution, unfortunately sending enter to this button doesn't work. Not sure why...

Comment: I have that happen too sometimes, especially when the click triggers a jQuery event. In that case I use `ExecuteScript` to perform the click, something like: `driver.ExecuteScript("$(arguments[0]).click()", elem);` Glad you found a workaround for now though.

Answer (score 1):

I use this script :

```
  private static void waitUntilScriptFoundAndExecute(String script) {
    int tries = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    do {
      tries++;
      try {
        driver.executeScript(script);
        found = true;
      } catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
        System.out.println("Wait for script NSE (" + tries + ")");
      } catch (WebDriverException wde) {
        System.out.println("Wait for script WDE (" + tries + ")");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Wait for script E (" + tries + ")");
      }

      // Waiting
      if (!found) {
        System.out.println("Wait for script Not found (" + tries + ")");
        waiting(SCRIPT_WAITING_INTERVAL);
      }
    } while (!found && tries < MAX_SCRIPT_WAIT_TRIES);

    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("Script aborted: " + script);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will not work for what I'm doing, while it is useful for looking for a script. Thanks. I ultimately found a solution and will post it once I'm able to. New users can't answer their own solution right away.

Comment: I am on same board how did u fix? Can u share? Edit ur question a d paste ur solution.

Answer (score 1):

**RepeatUntil Extension Method using LINQ Lambda expressions**

Copy this code to your project:

```cs
public static class SeleniumExtensionMethods
    {
        public static IWebElement RepeatUntil<T>(this T obj, 
             Func<T, IEnumerable<IWebElement>> func, 
                Func<IWebElement, bool> compare,
                  int MaxRetry = 20)
        {
            //call function to get elements
            var eles = func(obj);
            IWebElement element = null;
            while (element == null && MaxRetry > 0)
            {
                MaxRetry-=1;
                //call the iterator
                element = IterateCollection(compare, eles);
                if (element == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    //get new collection of elements
                    eles = func(obj);
                }
            };

            return element;
        }

        private static IWebElement IterateCollection(
           Func<IWebElement, bool> compare, 
           IEnumerable<IWebElement> eles){
            IWebElement element = null;
            eles.ToList().ForEach(
                ele =>
                {
                    //call the comparator
                    var found = compare(ele);
                    if (found) element = ele;
                });
            return element;
        }
    }
```

**Call it using this syntax:**

```
 // You can change PageObjectType to IWebDriver or IWebElement so that 
 // cb is of any type.
 var element = cb.RepeatUntil<MyPageObjectType>(
    //This is the first function to provide the elements
    p => p.FindElements(By.ClassName("TreeNode")), 
    //This is the comparator
    ele => ele.Text == nodeText && ele.Location.Y>YLocation);
```

Note: In the example above we are passing in a PageObjectType but you could change this to be of type IWebDriver or event IWebElement.  All the type parameter does it allow you to use this as an extension method for the type you specify.

Note the flexibility of the extension method in that the caller can determine the collection as well as the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

don't use thread sleep

```
public class(IWebDriver driver)
{           
this.driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
 }

public void class1()
{  
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elem)).Click();
}
```